# How to find web elements in web-view via Selenium WebDriver (Java API)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webview, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the `Selenium WebDriver (Java API)` to test an `electron/chromium` based application. The login page of this application has a `web-view` (`<webview>...</webview>`) which loads a secondary web page in it. I've attached a screenshot of a similar login page and its DOM below for your reference. As you can see in the screenshot, the `web-view` loads the secondary web page https://www.google.ca/ in this example. I'll need to interact with the web elements in this secondary web page. Let's say I'm trying to find the `Google Search` button and click it in this example as shown below.

```
WebElement googleSearchButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Google Search']"));
googleSearchButton.click();
```

Unfortunately, I can NOT seem to find any web element in the secondary web page via `driver.findElement(By)`. For example, the first line of the above mentioned code snippet throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

Does anyone know how to find web elements in a `web-view` via the `Selenium WebDriver (Java API)`?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Update the question with text based relevant HTML

Comment: In order to offer locator help, we need to see the relevant HTML. Please edit the question and add the HTML. What have you tried and what was the result? Please include full error messages, etc.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I've added the particular HTML DOM along with some sample Java code.

Comment: @JeffC, The particular HTML DOM along with some sample Java code is now available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going through [WebView](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag) documentation, I see that it is not recommended to use webview in the first place.

Now, coming to your question. You can go through this documentation and make use of JavascriptExecutor to interact with webview using webview's api.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2285

Open DevTools in console-tab execute `document.querySelector('webview').openDevTools();`
it will open you new window with desired HTML.

Or in case using jQuery `$('webview').openDevTools();`

Maybe just change `'webview'` to your locator, cause I have only one **webview** on the page.

Cheers.